# My App Build stuck at Processing, Prepare for Submission

Tags: app-store-connect

Uploading IOS App to AppStore. App Build stuck at Processing, Prepare for Submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spend too many hours on this issue

I found solution

every time I uploaded my build, apple send one email to my associated account like this:

Dear developer,

we have discovered one or more issue with your recent delivery for ..................................

Invalid Icon:   ................... AppICON24x24@2X.png with an alpha channel. Icons should not have an alpha channel

.......

Regards

The App Store Team